# SQL Server - CONCAT + IF em VIEW

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou com um problema e vou tentar explicar a situação.

Tenho uma tabela de clientes chamada `ENTIDADES`, nela existe um atributo chamado `ID_GRUPOECONOMICO` onde este é uma `FK` da tabela `GRUPOECONOMICO`. Estou criando uma VIEW para que retorne a quantidade de clientes em cada grupo economico e o atributo `GRPECON_DESCRIÇÃO` (é a descrição do grupo economico ex. CONTRATO BRONZE, CONTRATO PRATA, ETC).

Até aqui estou executando esta consulta:

```
SELECT
   CONCAT('Total de ', COUNT(E.ID_GRUPOECONOMICO), ' cliente(s) ' + GP.GRPECON_DESCRICAO) AS 'QUANTIDADE CLIENTE POR GRUPO ECONOMICO' 
FROM
   dbo.ENTIDADES AS E 
   LEFT JOIN
      dbo.GRUPOECONOMICO AS GP 
      ON GP.ID_GRUPOECONOMICO = E.ID_GRUPOECONOMICO 
GROUP BY
   GP.GRPECON_DESCRICAO
```

Ao executar esta consulta me traz as seguintes informações:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Neste resultado é apresentado um dos meus problemas, onde na linha `5` tras um total de 9 resultados que não tem nenhum `id_grupoeconomico` atribuído, ou seja, esta como `0`. Eu não estou conseguindo colocar uma condição para verificar se `NULL` e substitui por uma mensagem(`SEM GRUPO ECONOMICO`).
Preciso que esta informação venha como:

`Tota de 9 cliente(s) SEM GRUPO ECONOMICO`

Após este vem o problema maior, como aplico isto em uma `VIEW` pois quando tento cria-la, apresenta um problema com o `CONCAT()`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

olhando alguns posts eu mexi na consulta da `VIEW` para funcionar, porém nos resultados, a linha `5` vem como `NULL`(acredito que tem a ver com problema anterior).

```
SELECT
   { fn CONCAT('Total de ', CAST(COUNT(E.ID_GRUPOECONOMICO) AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' clientes ' + GP.GRPECON_DESCRICAO) } AS [QUANTIDADE CLIENTE POR GRUPO ECONOMICO] 
FROM
   dbo.ENTIDADES AS E 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
      dbo.GRUPOECONOMICO AS GP 
      ON GP.ID_GRUPOECONOMICO = E.ID_GRUPOECONOMICO 
GROUP BY
   GP.GRPECON_DESCRICAO
```

e o resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha dúvida é como deve escrever a consulta para tratar estes cadastros com id_grupoeconimico = 0 e se resolvendo a consulta, pode ser aplicada para a view também?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar o "CASE WHEN" pra resolver seu problema na primeira consulta, funciona como um IF:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT('Total de ', COUNT(E.ID_GRUPOECONOMICO), ' cliente(s) ' + CASE WHEN GP.GRPECON_DESCRICAO IS NULL THEN 'SEM GRUPO ECONOMICO' ELSE  GP.GRPECON_DESCRICAO END) AS 'QUANTIDADE CLIENTE POR GRUPO ECONOMICO' 
FROM dbo.ENTIDADES AS E 
LEFT JOIN
  dbo.GRUPOECONOMICO AS GP 
  ON GP.ID_GRUPOECONOMICO = E.ID_GRUPOECONOMICO 
GROUP BY
GP.GRPECON_DESCRICAO
```

Comment: Mto show, resolveu também para a `VIEW`, Obrigado @Júlio Neto

Answer (score 1):

A forma mais simples é aplicar um `ISNULL` na coluna `GRPECON_DESCRIÇÃO`:

```
SELECT      CONCAT('Total de ', CAST(COUNT(E.ID_GRUPOECONOMICO) AS VARCHAR), ' cliente(s) ' + ISNULL(GP.GRPECON_DESCRICAO, 'SEM GRUPO ECONOMICO')) AS 'QUANTIDADE CLIENTE POR GRUPO ECONOMICO' 
FROM        dbo.ENTIDADES       E 
LEFT JOIN   dbo.GRUPOECONOMICO  GP ON GP.ID_GRUPOECONOMICO = E.ID_GRUPOECONOMICO 
GROUP BY    GP.GRPECON_DESCRICAO
```

Não esquecer de fazer um `CAST` em `E.ID_GRUPOECONOMICO` porque se é do tipo numérico vai dar erro no `CONCAT`.

Comment: Valeu @João Martins, obrigado!